# Perform multiple commands on one line

Tags: shell, command-line

There are two steps, that I would like to be run on one line:

```
twinkle  -c
```

then

```
call  sip:in06khattab@sip.linphone.org
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I wanted to perform these two steps on one line, I tried `twinkle  -c && call  sip:in06khattab@sip.linphone.org`  and `twinkle  -c  call  sip:in06khattab@sip.linphone.org`  and `twinkle  -c ; call  sip:in06khattab@sip.linphone.org` and `twinkle -c --immediate --call sip:in06khattab@sip.linphone.org`

But they all give this response:[image]

Is there any way to get them on the same line?

**EDIT**:
The second command is being performed in bash rather than in Twinkle:
[image]

**EDIT** I tried `printf %s\\n 'call  sip:in06khattab@sip.linphone.org' |twinkle -c` which works for one seconds then closes itself (closes twinkle and returns to bash).It should remain in twinkle for the duration of the call.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `twinkle` is accepting stdin and executing commands. So...

```
printf %s\\n 'call  sip:in06khattab@sip.linphone.org' | cat - /dev/tty |twinkle -c
```

...should hopefully do it. If, instead, `twinkle` is one of those that reads `/dev/tty` explicitly, you can probably do...

```
printf %s\\n 'call  sip:in06khattab@sip.linphone.org' | cat - /dev/tty | 
luit -- twinkle -c
```

...or use perhaps `script` or `screen` in place of `luit`.

Since the former method apparently works for you, the following shell function might make it more simple to run at the command line. You should note, though, that both of the methods in this answer are kind of hacks - I originally wrote this then deleted it after the other answer was edited to include `--call`. I only undeleted it hours later when comments on the other indicated it wasn't working and I thought this might yet help. If it were me, though, I would try to find out *why* the other answer doesn't work.

Still, the shell function:

```
twinksip() while [ -n "$1" ]
           do    printf 'call sip:%s\n' "$1" |
                 cat - /dev/tty | twinkle -c || return
           shift;done
```

...which will prepend the `call sip:` prefix to all of its arguments and print them at `twinkle`'s stdin. It will process in order as many arguments as you give it, which, as I guess, would do many calls in a row - beginning the next when the last one ends.

You'd call it from the prompt like:

```
twinksip in06khattab@sip.linphone.org
```

Comment: tried printf %s\\n 'call  sip:in06khattab@sip.linphone.org' |twinkle -c which works for one seconds then closes itself (closes twinkle and returns to bash).It should remain in twinkle for the duration of the call. http://i.stack.imgur.com/sFm97.png

Comment: @Hamoudy - ahh, it quits when the input closes. Try the edit.

Comment: but does it call?

Comment: so close: http://prntscr.com/62fivt

Comment: @Hamoudy - you tell me - I've never heard of `twinkle` before and only made some educated guesses as to what it might be doing based on your screenshots and description of the problem. The function is just a named wrapper for the same command you said worked before. So you'd copy the function definition into ypur terminal *(or put it in your shell's rc file)* then call it as described at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

You have only a couple of ways of doing it:

```
twinkle  -c && call  sip:in06khattab@sip.linphone.org
```

With this option, the second command is executed when the first one end without error. In other case, the second one never executes.

```
twinkle  -c ; call  sip:in06khattab@sip.linphone.org
```

In this case, the second command is executed after the first one, no matter if the first end with or without error.

**Update**: I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
twinkle -c --immediate --call sip:in06khattab@sip.linphone.org
```

From [`twinkle`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/twinkle.1.html) manual page:

> ```
> --call <address>  
> Instruct Twinkle to call the address. When Twinkle is already running, this will instruct the running process to call the address. The address may be a full or partial SIP URI. A partial SIP URI will be completed with the information from the user profile.
> A subject may be passed by appending '`?subject=<subject>`' to the address.  
> Examples: `twinkle --call 123456 twinkle --call sip:example@example.com?subject=hello`
>
> --immediate
> This option can be used in conjunction with `--call` or `--cmd` It indicates the the command or call is to be performed immediately without asking the user for any confirmation.
> ```

Comment: same thing http://prntscr.com/62cn3b

Comment: same output at 5sec

Comment: look at the last line, it was performing the command in bash rather than Twinkle http://prntscr.com/62cqr6

Comment: Sorry I understand the wrong way. You want the second one executed on Twinkle, isn't it?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: yes, same thing http://prntscr.com/62cvr7

Comment: The last one. Try this: `twinkle -c --immediate --call sip:in06khattab@sip.linphone.org`

Comment: Thanks your your help, but the same thing: http://prntscr.com/62cyto